# How to encode multiple files with a batch file

Tags: encoding, x264

I am Encoding my own anime videos to save some space on my HDD using this script

https://gist.github.com/ScarletDevil25/9d71e4a7f5c215e558ecad158aa52600

However I can only encode one video at a time by dragging said video to the batch file and allowing it to run.

What I would like to be able to do is have the batch file encode multiple videos at once.

also as another question if someone could tell me how I would run this as admin